# Problems using contains() method for arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I am trying to check if an arraylist `B` contains a string from `arrayA` with this, but it doesn't work:

```
String match = arrayA[i];
if (! B.contains(match)) {
    outputFile.print(match);
}
```

Is this because I used the `contains()` method incorrectly?
Can we put the name of the variable in the `contains()` method like `contains(match)` here?
Or do we have to put a string in the `contains()`, like `contains("name")`?

Comment: The condition in your ``if`` statement is negated (indicated by the "!"), meaning that you only print stuff to the file if they DONT match. Are you sure that that's what you want?

Comment: You say it "doesn't work". Could you be more specific? What happens?

Comment: Note that "name" and a String with the value "name" will work the same way here. If I'm not mistaken they'll even point to the same String literal in memory. The difference is that the second one has a variable associated with it.

Comment: For more information look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
  if (! B.contains(match))
```

you check, if B does NOT contain match.
Apart from that, the approach is valid.

Comment: Thanks Christian! Yes I am trying to print out the elements that are not in the arraylist B.

Comment: Then your contains is correct. Is your program crashing?

Comment: No it's not crashing, but it does not print out the String match properly. Maybe it's because of the other methods but not this contains(). I will check it again. Thanks, the confirmation really helpful!

Comment: I'm guessing from the index `i` that you're doing this in a loop iterating over arrayA.  Are you sure that arrayA is initialized and contains what you think it contains?  Try adding an `else` clause that prints elements that are not in B.  If nothing is printed, then you'll know that arrayA doesn't contain what you expected.